# Ionic / Angular: EventListener called multiple times, after re-visiting the page

Tags: angular, ionic3, addeventlistener

The EventListener in my ionic/Angular app are called multiple times, after re-visition the page/view.

Code:

```
export class xyPage implements OnInit {

    constructor(
      ...
    ) {
        document.addEventListener('xzy', this.listenerFunction.bind(this));
    }

    private listenerFunction() {
        console.log('YAY');
        this.doSomething(this.options, this.timer);
    }

    ...

    ionViewWillLeave() {
            document.removeEventListener('xzy', this.listenerFunction.bind(this));
    }
```

When I visit my page the first time, everything works as it should.

After leaving and revisiting the page, I get the "log: YAY" twice. When I do that once again, I get it three times, and so on...

This problem only affects listener functions, that call sub-functions and require this.

Comment: add this befor `addEventListener` document.removeEventListener('xzy', this.listenerFunction.bind(this));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each visit creates a new event listener while the previous ones haven't been removed yet. Implement `OnDestroy` hook and remove the event listener using [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). This will remove the existing event listener when the component is closed/destroyed.

```js
export class xyPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(
      ...
    ) {
        document.addEventListener('xzy', this.listenerFunction.bind(this));
    }

    private listenerFunction() {
        console.log('YAY');
        this.doSomething(this.options, this.timer);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('xzy', this.listenerFunction.bind(this));
    }
   
    ...
}
```

---

That said, binding an event listener to `document` isn't elegant in Angular. Instead of searching for the specific component it'll search the complete SPA DOM. Instead you could use `@ViewChild` with a template reference variable and bind the listener to a specific element of the component. Instead of JS `addEventListener()` you could also use RxJS `fromEvent` to handle the event. Still in that case the subscription to it must be closed in the `ngOnDestroy` hook.

Comment: I updated my question, I have the 'removeEventListener' implemented. But probably wrong?!

Comment: @Bolin: Ideally you would be removing the listener that was bound in the `addEventListener` statement. So in your case it would be `document.removeEventListener('xzy', this.listenerFunction.bind(this));`, not an empty listener.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I changed that. Unfortunately this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Bolin: Then I'm not exactly sure. Perhaps you could try with `@ViewChild` and RxJS `fromEvent` like I suggested.